# Apache Cordova Android App: Front end app isn’t hitting the back end API

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, apache-cordova

I have a working web application hosted on AWS ec2. It works great from desktop and mobile browsers. The front end web application asks user to select a file and once done, invokes back end Python API. The front end then gets refreshed with the back end processing results.

This is now put inside Apache Cordova shell to create an Android app. This simply does not work - it doesn’t invoke the back end API.

Any specific permissions etc. that needs to be checked?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: To work with files in Cordova you should consider the file transfer plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer
Is this your case?

Comment: What doesn't work? Your entire app or just selecting the file? Do you get any errors?